# "ping -Mdo" won't prohibit fragmentation with MTU below 1500

Tags: networking, ping, ifconfig, mtu

I have encountered some trouble when testing different MTU settings on 2 nodes.

```
node1:192.168.160.2:MTU:1000
node2:192.168.160.3:MTU:9000
```

There is unmanaged switch between them. 
Path MTU Discovery is turned OFF

When testing traffic from node2 to node1, MTU below 1500 doesn't seem to be fragmented even though every packet above MTU 1000 should be dropped.

On node2:

```
root@192.168.160.3:~$ ping -Mdo -s 1472 node1
PING node1.lan (192.168.160.2) 1472(1500) bytes of data.
1480 bytes from node1.lan (192.168.160.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.227 ms
1480 bytes from node1.lan (192.168.160.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms
1480 bytes from node1.lan (192.168.160.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.265 ms
^C
--- node1.lan ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2061ms

root@192.168.160.3:~$ tracepath -l1504 node1
 1:  node1.lan                                            0.227ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1504 hops 1 back 1
```

On node1:

```
    root@192.168.160.2:~$ ping -Mdo -s 1000  node2
PING node2.lan (192.168.160.3) 1000(1028) bytes of data.
ping: local error: Message too long, mtu=1000
^C
--- node2.lan ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

root@192.168.160.2:~$ tracepath -l1500 node2
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1000
 1:  node2.lan                                            0.294ms reached
 1:  node2.lan                                            0.180ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1000 hops 1 back 1
```

Why packets aren't dropped on receiving end even though I'm not allowed to send them above set limit (1000)? Is there any additional mechanism that allows all packets below MTU value of 1500 be received that I'm unaware of? I wanted to create mechanism that would allow me to check MTU values on remote clients.

Comment: You are confusing what the MTU is. It is the Maximum _Transmission_ Unit, meaning that is the largest frame payload that a device will send, not the largest it will receive. The ethernet MTU is 1500, defined by the IEEE ethernet standard. If you lower the MTU on such an interface, the device will not _send_ packets (the frame payload) larger than the MTU, but it will continue to receive packets up to the IEEE MTU.

Comment: Fragmentation happens in routers along the packet path, as routers receive the packets on one interface and must send them out to another interface with an MTU that is smaller than the packet size. If the packet DF bit is not set, then the router must fragment the packet, and it will drop the packet if the DF bit is set. What you are interested in is the MTU of the interface for the last router in the path, which should be the same MTU as the destination host. The router should drop a packet with the DF bit set, and send back an ICMP message. That is the basis of PMTUD.